# Does object caching conflict with database query caching?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, object, caching

I'm curious since objects are likely built from data that is being pulled from the database, does this cause a conflict with plugins like W3 Total Cache when database caching is enabled along side object caching?

Answer (score 0):

No, caching is read only in both cases. However, Query caching is the actual query set, and the results (until they change). Object caching is the caching of the resultant data.

So look at it this way. Imagine you go to a shop several times a day. Everytime you order the same thing but you don't explain very well what it is that you need. Say for example it's a part to fix your tv, but you give some long winded explanation based upon the processes that this part fulfils.

Query caching would be akin to the shop assistant knowing what your long winded explanation means rather than figuring it out after 10mins of trying to decipher your explanation.

So, instead of you now explaining, assistant thinking, assistant working it out, assistant getting the part, you now have

You explain > assistant knows whats you need > assistant gets.

This is now 10minutes quicker.

However, if you apply object caching too:

You enter shop > Assistant knows what you want > assistant gets it from under counter

Now its so much quicker, you enter shop get the part and leave.

That's query caching and object caching combined. They are complimentary caching methods and do not 'conflict'. However, i suppose it all verges on what you consider to be a conflict.